# How to persist File object in Angular?

Tags: angular

is it possible to persist an object of type File, so i can restore it after form reload?
I am using Angular 10 (no Node).

Usecase:

1. In my form i have an <input type="file>.
2. The user can drag a file to it.
3. Later in the workflow the file is uploaded to my server.
4. If the user reloads the page, i want to request the selected file (of type "File") so i can upload the file without the user has to select it again.

Since the file does not contain the full path, i need to store/request it otherwise without loosing the connection to the upload stream.

Comment: You could add it into localStorage, but I don't think that will work for larger files.

Comment: Seems hard, indeed. What about sending the file to the API immediately, but save it in a temporary table (and move it to the real table when the user presses submit) ? And why would you allow the user to press F5 without losing his inputs ? Looks like the expected behavior...

Comment: @BojanKogoj i have tried it, but the local storage does not show any content, stringifying seems to be empty. And how to reconnect to the upload stream after reading from the storage?

Comment: @random Reason is that the workflow may include a redirect to another page and then coming back to my page. In this workflow the data should not be lost.
But sending the file immediately was the solution i had in mind too, but i hoped there is an easier solution.

Comment: It's a common solution. Either you create a "draft" object, and only publish on submit, or upload image, and add image to your form by id: but make sure to delete any images not associated after some time.

Comment: Yeah, to store something in the localStorage, you have to stringify it. If you know the format (txt, csv, json...) it may be a solution. If user may upload an image, you may use data-uri to stringify it, but that seems a lot of work to work in any situation...

Comment: storing the file content in local storage is no option, since the file may be very large